# Visual Studio подчеркивает

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Почему Visual Studio 2015 подчёркивает объявление функции волнистой линией и пишет

> не найдено определение функции

хотя оно есть и программа работает (при вызове этой функции выполняется код из определения)?

Объявление у меня в `.h` файле, а определение в `.cpp`. Всё остальное не подчеркивает.

Если воспользоваться IntelliSense и создать определение автоматически (сигнатура совпадает с неавтоматическим), то волнистая линия исчезает на время, я вставляю в новое определение код, удаляю старое определение, волнистая линия снова появляется :(

Если закомментировать код в определении, то подчеркивание исчезает!

Путём построчного комментирования также выяснилось, что подчеркивание вызывает строка, использующая `#define` из сторонней библиотеки

Comment: без выжимки из вашего кода ответить трудно. ошибка явно синтаксического характера.

Comment: @perfect если закомментировать код в определении, то подчеркивание исчезает! Как такое может быть?

Comment: Вполне может глючить VS. Создайте минимально возможный пример демонстрирующий проблему, чтобы другие участники могли проверить.

Comment: @alexolut дополнил вопрос. Сложно его создать, т.к. используется сторонняя библиотека

Comment: Залез в библиотеку, заменил за`define`йненую строку на оригинальную, подчеркивание исчезло О_О. Видимо, проблема в библиотеке

Comment: Если всё работает, а VS подчёркивает, тогда проблема в VS и больше ни в чём.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliSense использует несколько иной способ проверки и неправильно понимает области видимости для `#define` и `#undef`. В частности, если они находятся в одном файле и между ними есть код, в котором используется объявленное, оно там будет подчёркнуто.

Сталкивался с этим в более ранних версиях студии, могли уже и исправить.

Вообще, с этим ничего сделать нельзя. Просто игнорировать.